# Disabling Auto Standby on Overheating - is it possible?

Tags: windows-7

Seems that my Windows 7 had the temperature values misconfigured,
as that whenever it goes ~50 Celcius(GPU) it goes off.
It's working fine in Ubuntu, but not in Windows.
Is there any way that I could disable/modify it?
Any suggestions welcomed.
Model:
Asus A450LD-WX167D <-- Laptop
GPU - GT820M

Comment: Edited to make it more viewable. It's the GPU fyi, and the Cooling policy is in active state by default. A run-up using BOINC on GPU in Ubuntu works fine for the past week, but since I need to run some exe in Windows that wine aren't capable to run so I use BOINC for Windows when running my stuff. Whenever my Temp monitor software runs around 50 Celcius it goes standby automatically. This never happened in Ubuntu so I'd suspect that it's Windows' fault.

Comment: so only the screen/grafics is going into standby? Weird, some way to test the theory that it is the temperature for sure?

Comment: Playing games on Windows caused it(PSO2 on Medium-High setting), GPU Benchmark caused it(the benchmark gracefully exited in the process) and I don't think there is a problem in the graphics driver. The system goes into standby, as if I clicked the Standby from start screen.

Comment: As if the Dedicated Nvidia GPU , or the frame buffer transfer to the Intel on-die GPU stops/fails .  Do they allow you to force the dedi off , and use only the Intel gpu for testing?

Comment: Yes, and the Intel GPU works fine. anything around 105 Celcius will shut the laptop, still.